# JSP Struts parameter isn't showing

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag, ognl

I have below code, `testresultlists` is a list transferred to JSP, and `id` is named as `row`. The problem is I can't get each row's `resultTypeId` during select iterator.
In this `<s:if test="%{#result.resultTypeId == #row.resultTypeId">` I tried many ways, can't find a working way to show `#row.resultTypeId` result, but it has a value showing in another area.
Could anyone help me?

```
<display:table name="testresultlists" class="mobile" id="row" style="width:100%;"
    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" pagesize="50" requestURI="testExecutionAction.action" sort="external">
    <display:caption><thead>
    <tr  class="pageHeader">
        <th style="width: 5%;" >No.</th>
        <th style="width: 25%;">Test Case Name</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Result</th>
        <th style="width: 25%;">Log</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Bug Id</th>
        <th style="width: 25%;">Comments</th>
    </tr>
    </thead></display:caption>
    <display:column  title="Row Number" class="fixTitle1">
        <c:out value="${row_rowNum}"></c:out>
    </display:column>
    <display:column  property="testCaseName" />
    <display:column  title="Row Number" class="fixTitle1">
        <select id="${row.resultId}" name="${row.resultTypeId}">
        <s:iterator value="#resulttypelist" id="result">
            <s:if test="%{#result.resultTypeId == #row.resultTypeId">
                <option value="${result.resultTypeId }" selected="selected">${result.resultTypeName}</option>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                <option value="${result.resultTypeId }">233${result.resultTypeName}</option>
            </s:else>
        </s:iterator>
        </select>
    </display:column>
    <display:column  property="resultTypeId" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a getter for `resulttypelist` in the action class change this code

```
<s:iterator value="resulttypelist" var="result">
    <s:if test="%{#result.resultTypeId == #attr.row.resultTypeId}">
        <option value="${result.resultTypeId}" selected="selected">${result.resultTypeName}</option>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <option value="${result.resultTypeId}">233${result.resultTypeName}</option>
    </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```